# How to convert python dataframe timestamp to datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, strptime

I have a dataframe with date information in one column.

[image]

The date visually appears in the dataframe in this format: `2019-11-24`

but when you print the type it shows up as:

`Timestamp('2019-11-24 00:00:00')`

I'd like to convert each value in the dataframe to a format like this:

`24-Nov`

or

`7-Nov`

for single digit days.

I've tried using various `datetime` and `strptime` commands to convert but I am getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ["2014-10-23","2016-09-08"]}) 

df['date_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date_new'] = df['date_new'].dt.strftime("%d-%b")

         date      date_new
0  2014-10-23      23-Oct
1  2016-09-08      08-Sept
```